# Pandas long reshape for several variables

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reshape my long dataframe to wide by sorting it by `Session`. In this example `Session` is from 1-10.

```
       Session  Tube  Window  Counts  Length
0            1     1       1     0.0     0.0
1            1     1       2     0.0     0.0
2            1     1       3     0.0     0.0
3            1     1       4     0.0     0.0
4            1     1       5     0.0     0.0
...        ...   ...     ...     ...     ...
17995       10    53      36     0.0     0.0
17996       10    53      37     0.0     0.0
17997       10    53      38     0.0     0.0
17998       10    53      39     0.0     0.0
17999       10    53      40     0.0     0.0
```

What I am expecting is something like:

```
       Session  Tube  Window  Counts_1  Length_1           Session   Counts_2  Length_2
0            1     1       1     0.0     0.0    0                 2      0.0     0.0
1            1     1       2     0.0     0.0    1                 2      0.0     0.0
2            1     1       3     0.0     0.0    2                 2      0.0     0.0
3            1     1       4     0.0     0.0    3                 2      0.0     0.0
4            1     1       5     0.0     0.0    4                 2      0.0     0.0
...        ...   ...     ...     ...     ...    ...           ...   ...     ...     ...     ...
17995       10    53      36     0.0     0.0
```

I could not find the solution. What I tried leads to a complete wide dataset.

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby('Session').cumcount()+1
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Session'], columns='idx', 
                    values=['Counts', 'Length'], aggfunc='first')
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()

   Session  Counts_1   Length_1  Counts_2   Length_2  Counts_3   Length_3  Counts_4   Length_4  Counts_5   Length_5  ...  Length_1795  Counts_1796  Length_1796  Counts_1797  Length_1797  Counts_1798  Length_1798  Counts_1799  Length_1799  Counts_1800  Length_1800
0        1       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000  ...     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000
1        2       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000       0.0   0.000000  ...     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000
2        3       0.0   6.892889       0.0   2.503830       0.0   3.108580       0.0   5.188438       0.0   9.779242  ...     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000
3        4       1.0  12.787159       0.0  13.847412       7.0  44.928269       0.0  48.511435       2.0  33.264356  ...     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000
4        5       0.0  13.345436       2.0  27.415005      20.0  83.130315      19.0  85.475996       2.0  10.147958  ...     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000
5        6       2.0  13.141503       8.0  22.965002       5.0  48.737279      15.0  85.403915       1.0  17.414609  ...     0.000000          6.0    12.399834          0.0     0.710808          0.0     0.000000          0.0     1.661978          0.0     0.000000
6        7       1.0   7.852842       0.0  13.613426      14.0  46.148978      23.0  87.446535       0.0  13.759176  ...     2.231295          8.0    39.022340          1.0     7.304392          3.0     9.228959          0.0     6.885822          0.0     1.606200
7        8       0.0   0.884018       3.0  35.323813       8.0  32.846301      10.0  71.691744       0.0   4.310296  ...     2.753615          6.0    25.003670          6.0    22.113324          0.0     0.615790          0.0    11.812815          2.0     9.991712
8        9       4.0  24.700817      13.0  31.637755       3.0  30.312104       5.0  50.490115       0.0   3.830024  ...     5.977912         11.0    44.305738          1.0    13.523643          0.0     1.374856          1.0     9.066218          1.0     8.376995
9       10       0.0  17.651236      10.0  44.311858      29.0  55.415964      12.0  43.457016       1.0  41.503212  ...     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000          0.0     0.000000
```

Comment: Please give a smaller sample data that your code can run on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to pivot your dataframe, after building a custom index per session:

```
df2 = df.assign(index=df.groupby(['Session']).cumcount()).pivot(
    'index', 'Session', ['Tube',  'Window', 'Counts', 'Length']).rename_axis(index=None)
```

With you sample data it would give:

```
        Tube       Window       Counts      Length     
Session   1     10     1     10     1    10     1    10
0        1.0  53.0    1.0  36.0    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
1        1.0  53.0    2.0  37.0    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
2        1.0  53.0    3.0  38.0    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
3        1.0  53.0    4.0  39.0    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
4        1.0  53.0    5.0  40.0    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
```

Not that bad but we have a MultiIndex for the columns and in a wrong order. Let us go further:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_flat_index()
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=sorted(df2.columns, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

We now have:

```
   (Tube, 1)  (Window, 1)  ...  (Counts, 10)  (Length, 10)
0        1.0          1.0  ...           0.0           0.0
1        1.0          2.0  ...           0.0           0.0
2        1.0          3.0  ...           0.0           0.0
3        1.0          4.0  ...           0.0           0.0
4        1.0          5.0  ...           0.0           0.0
```

Last step:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(str(i) for i in x))
```

to finaly get:

```
   Tube_1  Window_1  Counts_1  ...  Window_10  Counts_10  Length_10
0     1.0       1.0       0.0  ...       36.0        0.0        0.0
1     1.0       2.0       0.0  ...       37.0        0.0        0.0
2     1.0       3.0       0.0  ...       38.0        0.0        0.0
3     1.0       4.0       0.0  ...       39.0        0.0        0.0
4     1.0       5.0       0.0  ...       40.0        0.0        0.0
```

Comment: Solved it almost perfect. I just had to get rid of ```['Tube', ' Window']``` in ```df.assign(index=df.groupby(['Session']).cumcount()).pivot('index', 'Session', ['Tube',  'Window', 'Counts', 'Length']).rename_axis(index=None)```. Then it worked as expected!